# Correct power steering hose replacement

Tags: honda, power-steering

Right now I am replacing my Power steering hose pressure line on my 02 Honda Odyssey. The reason I'm doing this is because I use the wrong seal on the return line fitting. The seal was too big and I forced the line, where I ended up bending the return line fitting, causing a leak.

Now I'm paranoid that I will install the return line incorrectly. I'm afraid that contaminants would enter the system after line R&R, then destroy the seals in the rack. What is proper replacement procedure that would prevent seal rupture from occurring? Is it only flushing the power steering system after service?

I am also cheapskate, but will not skimp on parts in this situation. I was thinking of filtering the old Power steering fluid I'm reusing it is because I recently changed it, or even not flushing it because It is new, but I think I will just use a couple of new 7$ Honda power steering fluid bottles.

Is fluid reuse a Stupid idea?

Comment: To my line of thinking, reusing the fluid is a non-starter. Two reasons: 1) New fluid really isn't that expensive in the grand scheme of things. 2) When I recently changed out the steering rack in a Civic, the instructions said new fluid was required to maintain the warranty. You are only changing out the line, but really, like you said, any contaminates you get into the fluid could cause you issues. Why risk $300-1000 on a new rack when you could have just spent the $15 on new fluid ... doesn't make a lick of sense. You cannot go wrong using new fluid. You ***CAN*** go wrong reusing the old.